# Centering contents of multiple colums

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a grid type layout, the contents of which will be centered, like here.

```css
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
<h1>I'm Centered</h1>
</div>
</div>
```

I've used `text-align: center;` but there should be a better way to center the contents vertically too. My issue arises trying to do the same where two of these are next to each other with centered content, like this;

```css
.outer {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.outer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
}
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-position {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-position">
              <p>I should be centered</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-position">
              <p>I should be centered</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It's looking even worse in a snippet for some reason but something like this would be desired;
[image: Example]
I can get the column layout or I can center content. I need to be able to do both.

`EDIT`

```css
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    background: pink;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.col {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
        position: relative;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
}

.inner {
    position: relative;
}

.inner-details {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    
    <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-details">
            <h1>Middle 1</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
        <div class="col">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="inner-details">
            <h1>Middle 2<h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you have a look at `display: flex` and the flexbox in general?

Comment: Yes @CornelRaiu, I want to use media queries and float them vs flex or a grid due to the layout being used.

Comment: you can make `.inner {display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center}` to center the content in the inner divs instead of doing the position absolute hacks. I am talking about the first snippet you added. It can be applied on `.inner-position` as well on the second example

Comment: That ends up adding margin

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/ have a look here. Hopefully you will understand and will be able to apply some things from here. I don't see why you would not use `display: flex` or `display: grid` to create the grid layout.

Comment: I could but I have a layout. I'm not against using them but I need it to be horizontal on desktop and stacked on mobile as well as centered within that

Comment: you can do that easily with `display: flex; flex-direction: column`. Just give it a try

Comment: Genuinely no idea how to also get the content centered. I'm thinking of just duplicating the first snippet and wrapping those two because there's no examples to work from

Answer (score 0):

To center items you can use `display: flex` on the container div and also use

```
align-items: center; // vertical
justify-content: center; // horizontal
```

To achieve the image you attached you don't need so many containers, this can be done simply like in this example:

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .inner-details {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
  }
}

.inner-details {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-details">
    <h1>Middle 1</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="inner-details">
    <h1>Middle 2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please look at the example I added

Comment: Close but the background needs to be on the main wrapper as it won't be a solid colour in the end. I've found an approach with more wrappers

Comment: OK, you can use the background where you want, but this is the core idea of the layout and it matches your image

Comment: I'm going to test a few variants now

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is your desire output. Please check the code snippets.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  margin: 10px 0; 
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .outer {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner-position {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-position">
      <p>I should be centered</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-position">
      <p>I should be centered</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's close (and fine for stacking them), there's no support for keeping it working horizontally

Comment: @learningtoanimate what do you mean no support for keeping it working horizontally? Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: If you see my answer and then resize the viewport you'll notice it adapts to the screen

Comment: @learningtoanimate that's because I'm using % for the height. Once I changed the height to fix value such as 100px, I think I get the same results as yours. Please check the code snippets again. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example from the first snippet and wrapping that twice I've managed to get the desired effect, there's still the issue with having to use `text-align` to align horizontally but this is the closest I can get without using `flex` or `box-sizing: border-box;`. If there's a more appropriate way to do this an example would be appreciated.

```css
.wrap {
 width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.col {
 width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col {
 width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.outer {a
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background: pink;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="col">
      <div class="outer">
         <div class="inner">
            <h1>I'm Centered</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <div class="outer">
         <div class="inner">
            <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```